# Solve the equation $\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^3+z^3} = \dfrac{1006}{1001}$

Tags: number-theory

> Solve the equation $\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^3+z^3} = \dfrac{1006}{1001}$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We must have $x^3+y^3 = 1006d$ and $x^3+z^3 = 1001d$ where $d$ is an integer. This means that $x^3+y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{1006}$ and $x^3+z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{1001}$. Rearranging the equation we also get $1001x^3+1001y^3 = 1006x^3+1006z^3$ so $$1001y^3 = 5x^3+1006z^3.$$ How can we continue?

Comment: There are no solutions, in my humble opinion

Comment: $1001y^3 = 5x^3+1006z^3$ looks similar to fermats equation for n=3, Maybe it can be shonw that nos solution exists in a similar way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A03

Comment: @L.Salvetti yes, the  x^3+y^3=z^3, has some solutions , too e,g, (1,-1,0)

Comment: @miracle173 Ignore my last comment, I knew it couldn't have checked so many numbers so quickly. I'm checking now for $-1000<x,y,z<1000$. https://imgur.com/PjrygRn

Comment: if x is even then y is even then 8 divides 1006 z^3 then .z is even and so gcd(x,y,z)>1. so we can assume x and y are odd.

Comment: You can argue that $503$ must divide either (both $x$ and $y$) or ($x+y$). Same $11$ must divide either (both $x$ and $z$) or $x+z$.

Comment: It's still running but so far it's got $(0,0,0),(669,337,332),(-669,-337,-332)$

Comment: My search finished: the only $x,y,z\in[-1000,1000]$ are those $3$ solutions I just listed.

Comment: here is a python program that searches x,y,z in (-1000,1000), takes about 3 minutes and outputs solutions with gcd=1 and sum signs>=1, so 669 337 332  and -1 1 1  https://repl.it/MzHR/10

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah that's a better way of doing it. I let mine carry on for $1000<x,y,z<2000$, with odd $x,y$ and it didn't find any other solutions. But mine missed $(-1,1,1)$ cause it was only checking for when $x,y,z$ were either all negative or all positive (not when $1$ was positive).

Answer (score 5):

Well, at least we have some solutions, like

$$\frac{669^3 + 337^3}{669^3 + 332^3} = \frac{1006}{1001}$$

This should be studied with elliptic curves.

May assume $x$, $y$, $z$, rationals, and then may even assume $x=1$. We get
$$\frac{y^3+1}{z^3+1} = \frac{1006}{1001}\\
z^3 +1 = \frac{1001}{1006}(y^3 + 1)$$

This is an elliptic curve, and it has an (easy) rational point ( does not give yet a solution to the problem) $(-1,-1)$. Now, take the tangent to the curve at this point and consider the intersection with the curve. It will be another rational point $(y,z) = (\frac{337}{669}, \frac{332}{669})$.

I lack expertise in elliptic curves, so  will leave it here.

$\bf{Added:}$ Took the tangent line to the curve at the last point and intersected it with the curve. Got another point
$$(y,z) = (-11901775977431/50258598213909 , -13216294942936/50258598213909) $$

I guess the question now is whether our elliptic curve has finitely many rational points.

Comment: the next one (35194680606174722389871263305780121256176854702373157111/201534300238681558991664322714087973929384858359949954443,13914800454401021146973131383289924825212913737256395856/201534300238681558991664322714087973929384858359949954443)

Comment: a maxima program that calculates the first solutions in the way you describe. It always return an errro (my local version does not) but nevertheless it calculates everything correct  https://goo.gl/fAww1a

Comment: @miracle173: that is pretty impressive! We might get infinitely many solutions in this way it seems.  This deserves some careful study.

Comment: is it really an elliptic curve, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) says $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ is an elliptic curve, but here  we have $y^3$?

Comment: @miracle173: yes, it is. But, even if we didn't know much, we can still do all these geometric things and produce rational points. Wiki give a standard form (Weierstrass form). But any smooth cubic curve gives an elliptic curve. We don't need to have it in standard form to perform all these operations, which are geometric.

Comment: @miracle173: there are ways to see whether we have infinitely many rational points on an elliptic curve. First, we need to reduce it to the canonical form, like wiki gives it. Then, there are sone online tools ( Magma online calculator) that would (with height probability) decide whether a certain elliptic curve has infinite rank ( infinitely many rational points).

Comment: @miracle173: I would recommend a book that give a bit more info: Silverman and Tate ...Elliptic Curves... see page 8 and on.